# How do I implement a division algorithm in ARM Assembly?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, arm, division

I am trying to implement the following algorithm in ARM assembly, but when I run my code in ARMSim 1.9.1, it prints out the quotient and remainder completely unchanged (0 and 5 in this case). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I think it is probably where I'm trying to set the rightmost bits of the register.

```
Given: Two positive integers: a Divisor X, and a Dividend Y
Use three General Purpose Registers (R, Q, X)
where R stores the Remainder, Q stores the Quotient, and X stores the Divisor. 
Steps:
    1. Copy Y into the Remainder register (R)
       Register Q will be initialized as 0 
    2. update: R =  R - X
    3. If R >= 0 then
        Shift the Quotient Register (Q) to the left (1 bit)
        and set the new rightmost bit to 1
       Else
        Restore the original value by of R:  R = R + X
            Also, Shift the Quotient Register (Q) to the left (1 bit)
            and set the new least significant bit to 0
    4. Shift the Divisor Register (X) to the right (1 bit)
    5. Repeat 31 more times
```

And here is my code:

```
.equ X, 12      @ the divisor - change to whatever number you wish
.equ Y, 5       @ the dividend - change to whatever number you wish

.global main

main:   
        LDR R6, =Y              @ R6 = R = Y
        MOV R7, #0              @ R7 = Q = 0
        MOV R8, #0              @ R8 = count = 0
        LDR R9, =X              @ R9 = X
loop:   SUB R6, R6, R9          @ R -= X
        CMP R6, #0              @ if R >= 0
        BGE _if                 @ goto _if
        CMP R6, #0              @ else if R < 0
        BLT  _else              @ else goto _else
        ADD R8, R8, #01         @ count++
        MOV R9, R9, LSR #01     @ shift X right 1 bit
        CMP R8, #32             @ if count <= 32
        BLE loop                @ continue looping

_if:
        MOV R7, R7, LSL #01     @ shift Q left 1 bit
        ORR R7, R7, #01         @ set rightmost bit to 1

_else:
        ADD R6, R6, R9          @ R += X
        MOV R7, R7, LSL #01     @ shift Q left 1 bit
        AND R7, R7, #2147483646 @ set rightmost bit to 0

exit:
        MOV R1, R7      @ R1 = Q
        SWI 0x6B        @ cout << R1
        MOV R1, R6      @ R1 = R
        SWI 0x6B        @ cout << R1
        SWI 0x11        @ exit
```

Comment: 5 divided by 12 *should* give you `Q=0` and `R=5`.

Comment: I can't see that it's be significant here, but "set rightmost bit to 0" clears both the lsb _and_ msb (i.e. the sign bit) - better to just use `bic r7, r7, #1` than inscrutable decimal constants. Also, there's no need to `cmp R6, #0` twice in a row - whether or not the first branch is taken doesn't affect the subsequent state of the flags. Anyway, consider what happens _after_ you've taken one of those branches to `_if` or `_else` - where does execution go next?

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. I mixed up what the divisor and the dividend were. Thank you! Should I use BX LR to return to the calling function after the if/else branches?